# How to conveniently read CV32E40P (ri5cy) register PCCR0?

Tags: c, embedded, cpu-registers, riscv

I want to read CV32E40P (ri5cy) register PCCR0 in c code and store the value into c variable.
Usually there’s an intrinsic C function to read the register, or the register is mapped to some address offset. But I cannot find it in the [Documentation](https://core-v-docs-verif-strat.readthedocs.io/projects/cv32e40p_um/en/latest/)

Comment: Could you point to some documentation describing this register?

Comment: I guess its new name is 'mcycle' [here](https://core-v-docs-verif-strat.readthedocs.io/projects/cv32e40p_um/en/latest/control_status_registers.html)

Comment: You need to check the compiler documentation if they provide C header files for reading / writing registers. I wouldn't expect to find the information in the CPU documentation.